# Using multiple gulpfile.js files in Visual Studio's Task Runner Explorer

Tags: visual-studio-2015, gulp, task-runner-explorer

Is there any way we can include multiple gulpfile.js' in the Visual Studio's Task Runner explorer? I wish to have separated files to handle individual node modules.

Comment: Still can't in 2017 :(